# Negative numbers in numpy.sqrt

Tags: numpy

I am writing code for a fluid flow simulation. I have an array initialized with the necessary parameters. I am using numpy's sqrt function on this array. The code is throwing out a warning as follows:-

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  W2[i, :] = (np.sqrt(P2) / (d2 * v2))
```

My code is running fine, and on further inspection, I found some negative values in the array, which goes inside the np.sqrt. My question is, what does numpy do with such discrepancies?

Comment: It outputs NaN for any negative numbers passed to sqrt. E.g. `np.sqrt(np.array([-1, 2, -3]))` results in `array([nan, 1.41421356, nan])`

Comment: I guess the one exception to that is that if you are using complex numbers, then NumPy will give you the complex number you get from the square root. e.g. `np.sqrt(np.array([-1, 2, -3]).astype('complex64'))` gives `array([0.       +1.j       , 1.4142135+0.j       , 0.       +1.7320508j], dtype=complex64)`. But you wouldn't get that warning if that were happening.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior on such occasionscan be controlled using [seterr()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) or [errstate()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html#numpy.errstate).

Depeding on the settings, errors may be ignored, produce a warning, raise an exception, call a given function, print or log the error.

When not raising an exception, NumPy produces a result including NaN or Inf values where appropriate:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, -1, np.nan, np.inf])
>>> with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
...     print(np.log(a))
...     print(1 / a)
[-inf   0.  nan  nan  inf]
[inf  1. -1. nan  0.]
```